# How to add a note to a Gitlab spent time tracking item

Tags: gitlab

In Gitlab I can add a comment of the following form to track time for an issue:

/spend 1h30m

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/time_tracking.html

The page shows, that it is possible to add notes. How do I add notes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the section titled [How to Enter Data](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/time_tracking.html#how-to-enter-data), you can enter your note and any `quick actions` in the same note. Quick actions are things like `/estimate 1w`, `/spend 3h`, `/approve`, `/assign @username`, etc. The list of all available `Quick Actions` is [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html).

For your note, as the `How to Enter Data` link suggests, you can enter your spent time and your note in the same comment:

```
# In the same comment:

Here's my comment text about some work I did

/spend 1h30m
```

When you submit that comment, the time spent will be updated in the Time Tracker, and a new comment will be added.

When you add a note and quick actions in the same comment, they aren't tied together in any way. Each item is processed separately. So if you had a note like this:

```
Here's a comment about some work I did

/assign @user2

/spend 2h
```

it would add a new comment with your text, it would assign `@user2` to the issue/merge request, and would add 2 hours of spent time to the Time Tracker.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without creating an unnecessary comment? Because with this approach the text used in the time tracking will still remain as a comment.

Comment: Yes! You’d use the same API but without any comment text, and just the quick action. In the backend, GitLab still considers it a “note” (like comments) but it renders it differently in the UI. It would show up exactly like it does when adding time via the GUI.

Comment: I meant how can I add a note to the time tracking report without creating a comment for it? If I create a comment with the note text and the quick action, then the text is added as a note to the report, but it also remains as a comment for the issue.